# Batch inserting characters in file names using ren in windows

Tags: windows, batch, rename

I would like to batch rename file names inserting 4 characters ("Lna_") within the fine name as:

```
Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Ft1.tif -> Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Lna_Ft1.tif , 
Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Ft2.tif -> Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Lna_Ft2.tif , 
Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Ft3.tif -> Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Lna_Ft3.tif , 
...
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split the names at the underscores with a parsing `for /f` and insert `_LNA` behind the 4th token.

In cmd line

```
for %A in (*_*_*_*_*.tif) do @for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=_" %B in ("%A") Do @echo Ren "%A" "%B_%C_%D_%E_LNA_%F"
```

If the sample output

```
Ren "Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Ft1.tif" "Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_LNA_Ft1.tif"
Ren "Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Ft2.tif" "Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_LNA_Ft2.tif"
Ren "Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Ft3.tif" "Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_LNA_Ft3.tif"
```

looks OK remove the echo in front of ren.

In a batch file double all the percent signs.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `for` construct, `ren` can only replace filenames with fixed characters

eg. `ren * *.bat` will change all filenames to end in `.bat`

`ren` allows (appending) suffix to filenames but not prefix (effectively, because both `?` and `*` wildcards include 0 instances).

In your case, you need to prefix some characters before characters which make the filenames unique, ie the numbers before the file extension: `.tif`, therefore a `for` & `ren` hybrid can solve this although, `for` command itself can do it alone, via tokenizing with underscores `_`, in this case.

Hybrid solution:

```
ren "*" "///////////////////*"
for %i in (*) do ren %i Cdt001_10x_G75_01s_Lna_%i
```

Tested in Win 10 cmd